# Matlab to C++ code conversion

Tags: c++, matlab, porting, percentile

## C++

this is my function call

```
int gr_tperctile = tprctile(channel_gr, sizeOfChannel, 0.2);
```

this is the function i wrote

```
int Detection::tprctile(int* gr, int sizeOfChannel, double pt)
{
    qsort(gr,sizeOfChannel, sizeof(int),compare);
    int ptInd = floor( (pt/100 * sizeOfChannel ) +0.5);

    return gr[ptInd];   
}

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

## MATLAB

this is the original function call

```
toolbox.c3d.p.tprctile(Gr(:),0.2)
```

this is the original function

```
function val = tprctile(data, pt)
   data = sort(data);
   ptInd = round( pt/100 * length(data) );
   val = data(ptInd);
```

I am not sure about my implementation and have tested it to limited number of example.
can anyone please tell me if this is correct? or a better way to implement the matlab

Comment: you might have an off-by-one bug when accessing into the data array; C++ uses 0-based indexing, MATLAB 1-based.

Comment: also if you want to return the n-th percentile of some data, there is a function for that [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html)

Comment: @Amro: Maybe he doesn't have the Statistics Toolbox, or doesn't want interpolation between samples.

Comment: BTW, if you think you have no errors (successful testing would make you think that) and want more eyes on your code, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++ (and from your use of classes, you clearly do), why would you use the slow, type-unsafe `qsort` function.  Instead try:

[`std::sort(gr, gr+sizeOfChannel);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

which replaces all of

```
qsort(gr,sizeOfChannel, sizeof(int),compare);
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

And did I mention it's faster?  That's because the comparison gets inlined.

As Amro points out, you can also use

[`std::nth_element(gr, gr+ptInd, gr+sizeOfChannel);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

which is faster yet.

Comment: in this case (percentiles), might just use STL's [nth_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/)

Comment: @Ben Voigt can please explain a little bit why sort is better than qsort

Comment: @Amro: Good point, since he only needs one result.  If you're going for, e.g. first quartile, median, and third quartile, might as well finish sorting.

Comment: @Gilad: It's typesafe (no messy casting like your `compare` function needs), and the comparison (defaults to `std::less` which uses `<`) gets inlined, so there aren't O(N lg N) extra indirect function calls.

Comment: std::nth_element doesn't return the same answer ass the function i wrote